# Объясните строку

Tags: c++

Вот сама строка,заранее спасибо

```
std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

Answer (score 2):

Отсортировать контейнер `v` от начала и до конца с использованием отношения "меньше" по умолчанию для элементов контейнера...

См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort